# Find words from text file containing 2 specified letters using php

Tags: php, arrays, find, words

I have a list of words in a text file say:

```
Adam
Tony
Bob
Chris
Tommy
```

And I have 2 letters say `t` & `y`

I need to find the words in the list containing both letters. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`file()`](http://php.net/preg_grep) and [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep). `file()` loads the words into an array, and `preg_grep()` returns array entries that match the pattern.

```
$words = file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$letters = array('t','y');
$result = preg_grep('/[ty]/', $words);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Tony
    [4] => Tommy
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/138228)

Comment: I was searching for a site where you can share php code and show the output. You are using exactly this for your demo. I am definitely going to use this along the way.

Comment: @Jouke: These might be useful, then: http://3v4l.org (allows you to test in 150+ PHP versions), http://codepad,org, http://codepad.viper-7.com (has `allow_url_fopen()` etc. enabled).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way..

```
<?php
$arr = file('names.txt');
foreach($arr as $v)
{
    if(strpos($v,'t')!==false && strpos($v,'y')!==false)
    {
        echo $v;
    }
}
```

#### Explanation :

Using `file()` the names are grabbed from the textfile into an array. Next , you do a `foreach` by cycling through the names one by one. Now you check whether `t` or `y` exists in the name and when found , you print the name of the person.

Using an `array_map()`

```
array_map(function ($v){ echo (stripos($v,'t')!==false && stripos($v,'y')!==false) ? $v :'';},file('new.txt'));
```

---

**`EDIT :`**

> what about when there are 2 letters that are the same though and I
>   want the words that contain that letter twice..??

```
<?php
$names=array('jimmy','jacky','monty','jammie');
$v='m'; //<-- Lets's search for twice of m occurence

foreach($names as $v1)
{
 $arr=array_count_values(str_split($v1));
  if($arr[$v]==2)
   {
    echo $v1."\n";
   }
}
```

#### Explanation :

As you can see `jimmy` and `jammie` are returned as output as we are searching for the `m` letter and they have twice of the occurrence and thus we print them up , whereas `jacky` and `monty` are ignored.

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
jimmy
jammie
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/138283)</kbd>

Comment: that's great thanks! what about when there are 2 letters that are the same though and I want the words that contain that letter twice..??